# Is it safe to include .gradle folder to my gitignore? If so why it is not included in default gitignore file generated by flutter create myapp command

Tags: android, git, flutter, version-control, gitignore

Is it safe to include .gradle folder to my gitignore?
If so why it is not included in default gitignore file generated by `flutter create myapp`
command?

`/.gitignore`:

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json
```

Comment: Well, i've been ignoring mine and its been ok so far. But maybe do a few tests to make sure? (like pull the project to a different folder and see if it still runs ok or something)

Comment: I deleted that folder. Rerun again everything is working great, and now git is ignoring that folder. Maybe git has own gitignore list precompiled. if not why .vscode(which is also hidden) folder is not ignored?

Comment: I also found that .gitignore_global file contains only .DS_STORE

Answer (score 0):

What the motivation of Flutter is to include or not include `.gradle` in generated `.gitignore` I can only guess, as I neither do Flutter, nor Android development.

But the `.gradle` directory just contains Gradle caches and similar and should never be versioned. I would really wonder if Flutter would have redefined that.

Also if you look at Flutter's own repository, they also ignore it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore
Or in their Gallery sample: https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/main/.gitignore

They have it under an "Android related" heading that you don't have at all in your file. Maybe you did not generate your project as "Android" project and thus this section was left out of your file or something like that? Just guessing for that last part.